# Do you have to join the broadcast group for IPv6 multicast?

Tags: ipv6, ip-address, multicast, igmp

When a client joins a network, is the client included in the ff02::1 IPv6 multicast group, which "broadcasts" to all nodes on the segment. OR, do I have to subscribe to the group using Multicast listener discovery with a report query including the multicast address group to subscribe to: ff02::1 in this case, I am guessing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this specific group is exempt from MLD.

RFC 3810 (MLDv2):

> The link-scope all-nodes multicast address, (FF02::1), is handled as
> a special case.  On all nodes -- that is all hosts and routers,
> including multicast routers -- listening to packets destined to the
> all-nodes multicast address, from all sources, is permanently enabled
> on all interfaces on which multicast listening is supported.  No MLD
> messages are ever sent regarding neither the link-scope all-nodes
> multicast address [...]

RFC 2710 (MLDv1):

> The link-scope all-nodes address (FF02::1) is handled as a special
> case.  The node starts in Idle Listener state for that address on
> every interface, never transitions to another state, and never sends
> a Report or Done for that address.
>
> [...]
>
> MLD messages ARE sent for multicast addresses whose scope is 2
> (link-local), including Solicited-Node multicast addresses [ADDR-
> ARCH], except for the link-scope, all-nodes address (FF02::1).

RFC 4541 (Considerations for IGMP and MLD snooping switches):

> [...] MLD is mandated for addresses with scope 2 (link-scope) or greater.
> The only exception is the address FF02::1 which is the all hosts
> link-scope address for which MLD messages are never sent.  Packets
> with the all hosts link-scope address should be forwarded on all
> ports.